# Asp.net Initial data in pull in UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, updatepanel

I have a dropdown list which gets populated from an odata service in Page_Load.
The dropdown list resides in an UpdatePanel control.

Currently the page does not load until the dropdown list is populated.

How can I make it so that the page loads initially and then keeps populating the dropdown list in the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do not load the DDL in Page_Load**

Let the blank DDL get rendered on the client side, then use AJAX or JavaScript to fetch records from the server and add them to the DDL.

Comment: Ok. How would you load a service into Ajax?

Comment: There are multiple options:
- Use AJAX timer and during the first tick event, load the DLL
- Use a separate web service method which will provide all the data through the Ajax call
- Use pure JavaScript/AJAX to load the records on demand

you can also add other options like instead of loading all records in one go, you can load in sets of n (like sets of 10/100 or whatever)